# I've added a javascript js file but when trying to use it, nothing happens

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've started a scaffolded ASP.NET MVC web app with individual user account authentication.

To implement a javascript feature:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Easy-Customizable-jQuery-Dropdown-Date-Picker-Plugin.html

I've done the following:

1. Added the js file to the "Scripts" folder (via right click on the "Scripts" folder in VS --> add --> etc. )
2. Used the following code in the register.cshtml file (a view file) :

   ```
           <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.date-dropdowns.js"></script>

           <input type="hidden" id="example">

           <script type="text/javascript">
               alert('Test');
               $("example").dateDropdowns(); 
           </script>
   ```

When in Visual Studio, I try to right click and go to the definition of the jquery "$" and I'm being taken to one. But, no such definition is found for "dateDropdowns()".

When I run the register view page, nothing happens or shown, only the test alert (I wanted to check that javascript runs)

Comment: is it showing any error in browser's console?

Comment: I suspect it's the path to the script folder. As far as I'm aware "~" is a server-side reference to the root of the application. Try changing it to src="/Scripts/jquery.date-dropdowns.js"

Comment: It's better if you add html also. My guess would be that $("example") finds nothing, you probably want to use `.example` or `#example` instead.

Comment: refresh the page and check the network, if js file loads

Comment: What is $("example").length ?

Comment: @RRR : the only error/warning I get is:

"DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337"

but I also get that on other pages ...

Comment: @Alex.Me : see Amit Kumar's solution, $("example") didn't find anything as you said. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to `#` for id selector.

Here is working example.

```
<input type="hidden" id="example">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IckleChris/jquery-date-dropdowns/master/src/jquery.date-dropdowns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#example").dateDropdowns();
    });
</script>
```

**[Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/pajxwbuq/)**

Comment: Thanks! It works now
But I still have two questions:
1) Is it supposed to work without the "#"? In the script website, the example is without a "#".
2) Why doesn't Visual Studio Intellisense find the definition of "dateDropdowns()"? (I right click it and select "go to definition")

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. it can't detect without `#` tag . It is jquery property. see list of selectors [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

right click and go to definition for server side code. If you want to see the definition of that function then check the [js file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IckleChris/jquery-date-dropdowns/master/src/jquery.date-dropdowns.js).  and yes there was mistake on the example page.

Comment: So what you're saying is that because "dateDropdowns" 's  code is client-side, Visual Studio won't find it's definition because Visual Studio links only server-side code?

Comment: try selecting whole word `dateDropdowns` then press `F12`

Comment: I get " 'Go to definition' failed"...
I also tried now going to "#" and "alert" definitions, it works for them.